# Help with お逃げになられるとは

Tags: grammar, translation, particles, manga

I began reading manga (To Loveる) and I saw something I don't understand or rather why it is used there.

The sentence is:

> まさか　こんな“辺境”にまでお逃げに**なられるとは**ねエ・・・

I mostly understand but there's the ending part that makes me confused.

1. Why is と even used there?
2. And what's with は?  Is it like ending-particle わ?
3. And one more: why is there used passive form of なる (なられる)?

Sorry for asking a lot! It would be great help if you could help me get it right.

Comment: と is quotative particle implying 思わなかった. は is what's called topic or contrastive particle.

Comment: No, I don't.  But thanks for asking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 「まさか、こんな”[辺境]{へんきょう}”にまでお[逃]{に}げになられるとはねエ・・・ 」

To give it my own TL,

***"Good Lord!  How you/he/she escaped all the way to this remote place!"***

> Why is と even used there?  And what's with は?

It is 「とは」 that we should be looking at here.

「～～～とは」 expresses the speaker's surprise, anger, excitement, etc.  The important thing is that one can end a sentence with this 「とは」 without directly stating how one feels about an event/situation.  The sentence in question is actually an example of this.  The 「ねエ」 ending does not count as a meaningful statement.  How the speaker feels is left unsaid.  Thus, the 「・・・」 at the end.

> Is it like ending-particle わ?

No, it is nothing like 「わ」.  To end a sentence with 「わ」, you need to make a meaningful statement first and then, you add a 「わ」 at the end.

> why is there used passive form of なる (なられる)?

That is not the passive voice; It is the honorific speech.  The speaker is being respectful to the person who ran away.

Comment: お逃げになられる（お～になられる）は正しい敬語ですか。「お逃げになる」でなくてよいですか。

Comment: 二重敬語で妙に丁寧なのは皮肉かなとか思ったんですけど・・

Comment: うわっ、あかん！ホンマやがな。若いな、ワシも・・