# What does this sentence mean: "これぐらいで, その始末とはな"

Tags: video-games

Dear users I have a question regarding a Japanese phrase I encountered in a video game.

Context: In the video game, a young boy survives a bandit raid on his home village. Unfortunately his father is killed. A wizard appears and rescues the boy, teleporting both away. As a result of the teleport, the boy throws up and the wizard says "これぐらいで, その始末とはな". I don't quite know how to translate this sentence. The scene occurs e.G. on this video on minute 24:49

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I8j2cX_tVpc&list=PLlSLks4jF4aCTf3cC19pbDoVn42JzoC_A

Could you help me?

Comment: Hi Kagemusha, thanks for your first question on Japanese Language Stack Exchange. The way you have currently phrased your question, it seems like it would be off-topic as it constitutes a direct translation (see: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). If you could edit your question to explain your difficulties and demonstrate your research effort, however, it would be (at least closer to being) on topic, I think. Otherwise, your question may be closed. Hope that helps.

Comment: Nobody can translate this phrase without the context.

Answer (score 2):

- **これ**: "this" (= the teleportation)
- **ぐらい**: "only", "just"
- **で**: "with", "by"
- **その**: "that" (refers to something close to the listener)
- **始末**: "(bad) result/outcome" (refers to the boy's situation)
- **とは**: exclamatory expression (see [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/25323/5010) and [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/24976/5010))
- **な**: sentene-end particle

Put together, a literal translation would be "Only with this, (you ended up with) that (result)!" You can change this to make it look more natural in English.

<sub>By the way, please read the comment by henreetee. You have shown your proficiency in Japanese, but it's always best to show your translation attempt for the sentence in question. Otherwise people have to explain every single aspect of the sentence...</sub>